# Run a command in a batch file on the system clock

Tags: windows-7, command-line, operating-systems, batch-file, clock

I have two different connection for my internet connection. 
The first uses from 7am to 10pm. 
The second uses from 10 pm to 7 am the next day. 
And for each of the connections I've made a batch file to connect to the Internet. 
With the command "rasdial connectionA ......" within each file separately.
Now I want to make another batch file that when executed. 
Based on the system clock, perform one of these files automatically. 
For example, if it was 9 am, recognizing that now is the time between 7 am and 10 pm so run an “A” file.
please learn me what is a command(s) for it?
My English is weak so I'm sorry.

Comment: Not sure if batch is really good for this. How do you feel about PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, with PowerShell:

```
$CurrentHour = (Get-Date).Hour
if ($CurrentHour -ge 7 -and $CurrentHour -le 22)
{
    <# Insert commands for 7 AM to 10 PM connection here. #>
}
else
{
    <# Insert commands for 10 PM to 7 AM connection here. #>
}
```

The nice thing about PowerShell is that it still retains access to the commands you would normally use with CMD/batch. So, you should be able to just put your `rasdial` commands in place of the comment lines above.

If you want to run a test to make sure the if statements are working properly, you can set the time used by `Get-Date` with the `-Hour` parameter. For example, change the first line to `$CurrentHour = (Get-Date -Hour 10).Hour` to test for times within the 10 AM hour.

Unfortunately, PowerShell doesn't get a lot of native networking commands until you upgrade the OS to Windows 8 or Windows 8.1. There may be some ways you can do it by accessing the underlying .NET Framework objects, but you're probably better off just sticking with `rasdial` for now.